# Parse space separated log into hash using perl

Tags: perl, hashmap

I want to store each line of a log (will only ever be 2 lines) into separate hashes and then check each keys value to determine if there has been an increase or a decrease. The log file may not have matching protocols each time, so rdp is missing from line 2, and there may be a new protocol entirely which is why I thought using a hash would be a good idea.

```
tcp 217837 tls 138531 http 50302 udp 37852 dns 23625 ldap 14160 krb5 8828 smb 2148 ssh 549 ftp 219 smtp 161 icmp 6 rdp 3 ssdp 3
tcp 198650 tls 125770 http 44260 udp 37610 dns 23827 ldap 13904 krb5 8805 smb 2128 ssh 629 ftp 219 smtp 156 icmp 5 ssdp 1
```

What I want to do is read the first line into a hash so it looks like this:

key value

tcp:217837

tls:138531

Then I want to read the second line into another hash in the same manner:

key value

tcp:198650

tls:125770

How could I accomplish this? I've tried to search but many of the examples rely on having the log file formatted differently. I would like the solution to be in Perl if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash can be populated by a list, where consecutive elements are paired up as key-value

```
my %hash = ('a', 1, 'b', 2);   #--> %hash is (a => 1, b => 2)
```

so you can do that with each line, by splitting it on whitespace

```
open my $fh, $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
my %line_1 = split ' ', <$fh>;
my %line_2 = split ' ', <$fh>;
```

or, to not limit yourself to two lines only

```
while (<$fh>) {
    my %line = split;
}
```

where `split;` uses [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)  defaults and so is the same as `split ' ', $_;`

This will create new hash(es) every time.  Even if you declare them elsewhere and repeatedly read into those variables in this way, it will still overwrite every time. If you need to update an existing hash read into a temporary one and then update/check the main hash key by key.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<>) {
   my %hash = split;
   ...
}
```

or

```
while (<>) {
   push @hashes, { split };
}

...
```